Where permeability first appeared?
I have just started studying magnetism and seen that permeability (μ) first appeared while describing Biot-Savart Law. So, I thought μ is defined using Biot-Savart Law. Then I kept on reading and found that Magnetic Flux Intensity due to magnetization and the Magnetization Intensity is related like this:  $B_m = μI$, where I is Magnetization Intensity. Though the proportionality of $B_m$ and $I$ in intuitively understandable to me, but for equality we have introduced something, which is defined earlier. Generally, we define the proportionality constants using the proportional relation itself (in such a way that the equality holds). So, is μ defined here first or in Biot-Savart Law? If it is first defined in Biot-Savart Law, then how that exactly fitted to turn the later proportionality into equality? Or we may ask the question reversely also for Biot-Savart Law.

https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Maybe the best answer is that it doesn't matter where something is "first defined" as long as you understand what it is.  The local gravitational constant $g$, for example, is a number that describes 1) the (initial) acceleration of an object in free fall, and 2) what you multiply mass by to get force, at least in proper units.  These two things are related, of course.
About $\mu$ I would argue that it is a material property that relates what you call $I$ (but I call $\bf H$) and $\bf B$ inside certain materials and that this is the more fundamental definition.  I should warn you that the situation in magnetic materials is much more complicated than simply writing $\bf B$ = $\mu \bf H$, and that you may encounter different unit systems where the equations look different, but that is beyond the scope of your question.
Note that you can re-write the Biot Savart law in $\bf H$ instead of $\bf B$ and no $\mu$ or $\mu_0$ appears, in support of my point above.
Hope this helps.
12/24/24  Extended answer to comment below.
Units can be confusing, and magnetostatics is no exception.  There is an older unit system that uses the formula "$\boldsymbol{B} = \mu \boldsymbol{H}$" with unitless $\mu$.     I am most familiar with the SI unit way of writing things, where the old $\mu$ is now called "relative $\mu$", typically written $\mu_r$.  In SI units, $\bf B$ and $\bf H$ have DIFFERENT units (Tesla and Amps/meter, respectively).   They are linked by the vacuum permeability $\mu_0$ which approximately equals $4 \pi \times 10^{-7}$ H/m.  So in my world, the formula would look like $\boldsymbol{B} = \mu_r \mu_0 \boldsymbol{H}$ where the "total $\mu$" is $\mu_r \mu_0$.
In typical SI formulation, we take the complete effect of magnetization into account by writing
$$ \boldsymbol{B} = \mu_0 (\boldsymbol{H} + \boldsymbol{M})$$
where $\bf M$ is the magnetic dipole per unit volume that you mention, and it DOES have the same units of A/m as $\bf H$, analogous to what you are calling $I$.  $\bf H$ and $\bf M$ are also linked by the magnetic susceptibility denoted by $\chi$, which is dimensionless.  So we can write $\boldsymbol{M} = \chi \boldsymbol{H}$.  If you work through the formulas you will find the relationship $\chi = \mu_r - 1$ which is consistent with.
$$ \boldsymbol{B} = \mu \boldsymbol{H}$$
If $\mu_r = 1$ then $\chi = 0$ and $\bf M$ (or what you call $I$) is also $\bf 0$.
All of the above is ONLY true when assuming that a material is linearly magnetic (which is almost never a perfect assumption) and not saturated.  In particular, when trying to understand permanent magnetism, $\bf B$ is a nonlinear function of $\bf H$ and $\mu$ is defined differently (if it is used at all.)
See also this Wikipedia page for a different way of explaining the same thing.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field
Note that none of this changes my original observation that one can write Biot-Savart without reference to any $\mu$.

So far I know, though the units are same for H and I, there is a subtle difference. According to your answer, we may consider that H was first defined using Biot- Savart law(without using mu) and B was defined using F = qvBsin(theta) then we defined mu as a relationship between them. But I has a completely different and independent definition, that is the magnetic dipole moment per unit volume. How the same mu we use to handle H now handling I nicely?

I reply to your question in an addendum to the answer above.

Thank you very much, I have struggled with the confusion of μr and μo in these formulae for a long time. Hope I have understood them correctly now.

I think Permeability is defined in biot law  first of all in magnetism when  they were searching magnetic field due to a single  part of currect  element ( that tiny part)
In magnetism  ,  intensity of magnetisation is defined in such a way that it related to magnetic field of magnetised material by the relation you wrote...  Means  magnetic field intensity of that  material regardless of permeability of vaccum
I understand it as
I is defined  as-
After the object is magnetized
Magnetic field  inside it is same as  Magnetic field in vaccum with  magnitude of mu knot times I

But I is defined in another way also, the magnetic dipole moment per unit volume. How this definition gives the same answer as your definition? They seem completely independent of each other to me.
